# Find all clickable elements using webdriverio

Tags: webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I am new to webdriver io and I want to get all clickable elements using webdriver io and iterate through them. I came across 'browser.findElements' API, but could not get it to work. Can anyone provide me a sample code ?

```
var assert = require('assert');
var homePage = require("../../pages/home_page");

describe('Keyboard friendly home page', () => {  
  it('User should be able to navigate using tab',() => {
    browser.url(homePage.url);
    elements = browser.findElements("div");
    clickableElements = [];
    elements.forEach(element => {
      if (element.isDiplayed() && element.isClickable()) {
        clickableElements.push(element);
      }
    });

    
    clickableElements.array.forEach(element => {
      console.log(elemtent.getText() + "is clickable");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

There might be two problems with your example:

1. incorrect use of `findElements`, see [documentation](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html#findelements); you can use [`$$` command](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/$$.html) where you pass only a selector, no need to pass a location strategy as well
2. the last `forEach` loop should look like this:

```js
clickableElements.forEach(element => {
    console.log(elemtent.getText() + "is clickable");
});
```